# Count files in google drive enterprise

Tags: google-drive-api

how can you get the number of files in my company's google drive enterprise account using google drive sdk? is there anything like that available from google drive apis?

How can we systematically get:

- Number of files in my enterprise
- Space taken in my enterprise
- The number of files per user average
- The number of space taken per usage average

I Do *not* want to crawl all users looking for a single lookup. If it has to be an email to google enterprise support then so be it.

Comment: There seems to be no ad-hoc function for this. Have you tried if running [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) works where you put the response inside an array and perform an array.length?

Comment: look at the gsuite admin reports. show us your research there first.

Comment: yes. i know how to list the files not what i want. the gsuite admin reports sound like a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

As @zig suggests, check what is available in admin reports first.

If that draws a blank, you can write a simple routine that gets a list of users, then foreach user use a service account to impersonate that user and use files.list to count the files.

Comment: any idea where to look in the gsuite admin reports?

Comment: i found nothing. i see ways to view files and stuff.... but no way to see the total size used?

Comment: and the counting each user's size is not as trivial as mentioned, but that is what i am already doing and trying to avoid.